# "ReferenceError: handler is not defined" in Node.js

Tags: node.js, undefined, handler, referenceerror

This is the first line of my Node.js app:

```
var app     = require('http').createServer(handler);
```

When I try to start it doing `node index.js` the result is:

```
/home/username/public_html/index.js:1
var app     = require('http').createServer(handler);
                                           ^
ReferenceError: handler is not defined
```

*My Node.js version is **0.12.4***

Comment: Did you define a function named `handler`?  It is telling you that there is no symbol named `handler`, yet your code is referring to one.

Comment: show us the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that's the first line of your code. The problem is that you do not define the `handler` variable. It should be a function that responds to a request event. Since it is optional, you can (if you wish) leave it out entirely and add handlers for events later on.

```
var app     = require('http').createServer();
```

Comment: Exactly. I have suppressed the handler function because I don't need it, and forget to remove it in this line.